# Combinatorics question- 8 football games- how many end with 4 wins, 3 losses and a tie

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A college plays 8 football games during a season. In how many ways can the team end the season with 4 wins, 3 losses and a tie?

I started this question by trying to count the total number of possible permutations of wins, losses and draws for the 8 games: $3^8$.

I then thought I would divide the total by the number of kinds that I have-

$\frac {3^8}{4!3!}$

This doesn't work as I don't get the correct answer. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the wins can be selected in ${8\choose 4}$ ways now losses can be selected in ${4\choose 3}$ ways while only one way is left for tie.so toyal ways are their product=$70.4.1=280$ now another approach consider set{WWWWLLLT} in how many ways can you arrange these letters so its $\frac{8!}{4!.3!}$ which is again equal to $280$ hope its clear .

Comment: Very clear. Thanks for the second method,

Answer (score 3):

First choose the four games that are won among all the eight games, then the three games that are lost among the remaining four, and finally the one draw. This gives:

$$\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1}=70\cdot4\cdot1 = 280$$

unique possibilities. By the way, this is also equal to the multinomial coefficient $\binom{8}{4,3,1}$

Comment: Ah beat me to it. Thanks, this makes perfect sense.

Comment: It should be $280$ please correct the typo

Comment: I have added another approach in my answer. For your second approach